# How to send a Retrofit2 HTTP request with a Query?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to send an **HTTP request** using **Retrofit 2**, the request contains a **query**. I sent a request with a query exactly as explained in many different places but it still doesn't work.

> Request:

```
@POST(myURL)
    Call<SearchActivityRespone> getResponse(@Query("id") int id,@Header("authorization") String code);
```

> Request call:

```
final Call<Response> ResponeCall = service.getResponse(1, code);
```

I do not know why it does not work, it successfully sends the request and receives a reply, but the query fails. It doesn't change anything if I replace @Query and @Header (Lest anyone suggest it)...

Comment: Is there any error message or something which can help us to identify issue?

Comment: You have to use "Authorization" instead of "authorization".

Comment: will you please tell more  what kind of failure

Comment: ```@Query``` work with @GET I think

Comment: @Agnaramon No, it will work with ``POST`` too

Comment: There is no error

Comment: Have tried in POSTMAN your request?

Comment: Does anyone know the answer?